# Different definitions of fractional sobolev spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, laplacian

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded and smooth domain in $\mathbb R^d$. For any $s\in (0,1)$ we can define $H_s(\Omega)$ to be the space of functions $u\in L^2(\Omega)$ such that $$(x,y)\mapsto \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{\frac{d}{2}+s}}\in L^2(\Omega\times \Omega)\, .$$
We can also define the space $\tilde H_s(\Omega)$ to be the set of functions $u\in L^2(\Omega)$ such that $u=\sum_{k\geq 1}u_k \Phi_k$, and $\sum_{k\geq 1}\lambda_k^s u_k^2 <+\infty$, where $\lambda_k$ and $\Phi_k$ are the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on $\Omega$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions.

My question is the following: do we have $\tilde H_s(\Omega)\subset H_s(\Omega)$, where the inclusion is continuous?

Comment: Did you ever manage to discover the answer for this?